# jQuery selector in context

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get this to work: `$( '> p', this )`. Essentially I want to get the `<p>`s directly in `this`, any ideas?

Comment: That should work. But what is "this" ?

Comment: is this inside a function? you could do $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' > p')

Comment: Your code works, here is an updated version of Chris Sobolewski's jsfiddle with your contextual selector and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EWRtR/1/

Comment: You're all right, I wonder if SO will allow me to accept multiple answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do this... `$(this).children("p")`

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$(this).find('> p');
```

Or:

```
$(this).children('p');
```

But these both achieve more or less exactly the same thing as your current selector; so until you explain what doesn't work, or what goes wrong, I can't offer specifically useful advice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you...

```
$(this).children('p')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('>p',this)
```

Should give you any `<p>`'s that are a child of the this element (Assuming this is jquery element)

Here's a fiddle I created to verify this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jberke/GFe2H/1/

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).children('p')` will work just fine.

See this fairly cludgy example:

http://jsfiddle.net/EWRtR/